# What's the purpose of multiple asset sources?

Tags: assets

If I have just one S3 bucket, should I still have multiple asset 'sources' in order to account for different asset types? Or should I just have multiple folders under single asset source to differentiate media types?

For example, I might have these folders under a single asset source:

- Illustrations/Icons
- Marketing Images
- Screenshots
- Marketing Videos
- Support Videos

It just seems silly to add multiple asset 'sources' when the details are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the bucket directory structure for the different asset types; you're right, they are all coming from the same source, really, so separete asset sources wouldn't be correct.

Another asset source would be simply another bucket, or another type of source such as Google Cloud or Rackspace.

You could have an asset source called **Web S3 Assets**, which connects to your bucket.

As an example, you could have these directories within that bucket for all the types of assets you need to store.

- `<bucket-url>/images/icons/`
- `<bucket-url>/images/illustrations/`
- `<bucket-url>/images/screenshots/`
- `<bucket-url>/videos/marketing/`
- `<bucket-url>/videos/support/`

Use [Assets Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields) to force usage, upload restrictions on these directories.